# Unable to Call Reconnect API

Tags: php, oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying to connect Reconncet API of QuickBooks. It always says me 'This API requires authorization' I dont understand what does it  mean.

```
$nonce = <random string>;
    $time = time();

    $url = "https://appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Connection/Reconnect?oauth_consumer_key=qyprdxncjBz7mV8ZUJVlc155xTMEOe&oauth_nonce=$nonce&oauth_signature=eiDxzuLEFveRoXDBrt58nitVc2IMTcQjOczy81Bl%26Nyxwe3eEwPMKx5qM9FwzOTZjw7jUPaHaaa9z74cH&oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT&oauth_timestamp=$time&oauth_token=qyprd2P9wwoF6mn8PhSZDK6RlwTCpH0neeZQHKWdokxdl2AQ&oauth_version=1.0";

    $params = Array
    (
        19913 => 1,
        10002 => $url,
        10023 => Array
            (

            ),

        10102 => '',
        41 => 0,
        64 => 0,
        81 => 0
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $params);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($response);
```

Please help me over this problem. I really need this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The reconnect API requires that you pass in a valid set of OAuth headers in order to authenticate, so that it can then renew your soon-to-expire OAuth tokens.

The important thing to realize here is that *you can't just invent your OAuth header string*, there's a very specific signing algorithm you have to follow.

By hard-coding it like you posted above, there's no way those are valid OAuth headers.

Unless you're very familiar with OAuth already and want to roll your own, [use the existing QuickBooks PHP library](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) that [already has reconnect API support](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_app_ipp_v3/reconnect.php).

If you really want to roll your own (you don't) then [read and implement the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849).